# Cómo cambiar una fórmula de Excel a Python y optimizar el proceso

Tags: python, excel

Estoy intentando pasar una fórmula de Excel a Python. La fórmula funciona bien pero se demora bastante en hacer el recorrido. Se tienen 4 columnas:

Ceros,ID,FechaIngreso,FechaSalida.

Las condiciones de Excel son las siguientes
`=SI(Y(B3=B2;C3=C2;D3="";D2<>"");1;0)`
La primera fila no se toca y la fórmula se aplica a partir de la segunda fila.

El código que hice en python es el siguiente

```
n=df.shape[0]

for i in range(1,n) :
    if ( df["ID"][i]==df["ID"][i-1] and df["FechaIngreso"][i]==df["FechaIngreso"][i-1] and
       str(df["FechaSalida"][i])==str( pd.NaT ) and str(df["FechaSalida"][i-1])!=str( pd.NaT ) ):   df["Ceros"][i]=1
    else : df["Ceros"][i]=0
}


for i in range(1,n):
    if (df.loc[i,'Ceros']==1 ) : df.loc[i,'FechaSalida']=df.loc[i-1,'FechaSalida']
    else : df.loc[i,'FechaSalida']=df.loc[i,'FechaSalida']
```

Como lo mencioné, hace lo que necesito pero se demora mucho. Hay alguna manera de optimizar el código?

Adjunto dataframe.[Enlace base Formulada](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KLhi_vq4YjvbD8ueCdEozG8FauXrpNYh/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104604585521017568199&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Estas usando pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente puedes optimizar tu código y bastante, utilizando la manera de trabajar con pandas como un todo, y no como lo estás haciendo celda por celda. Una posible vía:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Formulada.xlsx")
dfshift = df.shift(1)

x = df == dfshift
df["Ceros"] = x["FechaIngreso"] & x["ID"] & df["FechaSalida"].isna() & dfshift["FechaSalida"].notna()
df["Ceros"] = df["Ceros"].astype(int)

df.loc[df.Ceros == 1, "FechaSalida"] = dfshift["FechaSalida"]
print(df)
```

Que da como salida:

```
    Ceros  ID FechaIngreso FechaSalida   FechaAct
0       0   1   2020-11-01  2021-01-13 2021-07-31
1       0   1   2020-11-01  2021-01-12 2021-01-13
2       1   1   2020-11-01  2021-01-12 2021-01-12
3       0   1   2020-11-01         NaT 2021-07-31
4       0   5   2022-04-25         NaT 2022-04-25
5       0  15   2018-11-20  2019-11-08 2019-11-08
6       0  16   2021-02-09         NaT 2021-07-31
7       0  17   2021-07-31  2021-12-13 2021-12-13
8       0  18   2022-04-12  2022-04-29 2022-04-29
9       1  18   2022-04-12  2022-04-29 2022-04-12
10      0  18   2022-02-10         NaT 2022-02-14
11      0  19   2020-08-10  2020-10-07 2020-10-07
12      0  20   2022-03-18  2022-04-11 2022-04-11
13      0  20   2020-08-18         NaT 2020-08-19
14      0  21   2020-11-01  2022-02-02 2021-10-31
15      1  21   2020-11-01  2022-02-02 2021-11-10
16      0  21   2020-11-01         NaT 2021-07-31
17      0  32   2022-04-25         NaT 2022-04-25
18      0  32   2022-03-25  2022-04-04 2022-04-04
19      1  32   2022-03-25  2022-04-04 2022-03-25
20      0  32   2022-01-25  2022-02-11 2022-02-11
21      0  33   2022-04-12  2022-04-26 2022-04-26
22      1  33   2022-04-12  2022-04-26 2022-04-12
23      0  33   2022-02-10         NaT 2022-02-21
24      0  34   2021-07-26         NaT 2021-07-28
25      0  35   2022-02-08  2022-03-10 2022-03-10
26      1  35   2022-02-08  2022-03-10 2022-02-08
27      0  36   2021-07-31  2022-05-04 2022-05-04
28      0  37   2022-04-25  2022-05-04 2022-05-04
29      0  38   2022-04-12  2022-05-04 2022-05-04
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esa manera redujo el trabajo de 7 minutos a 1 segundo! Fascinante.

Comment: Wow! Si que hizo diferencia. Me alegra te haya funcionado. Si hay algo que debes evitar  a toda costa cuando estás trabajando con pandas son los ciclos. Generalmente los ciclos en tu código para iterar tu dataframe son señales de que estás haciendo algo mal.